# At what league do players on team match tend stay for a game in Star Craft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

First to note, I've been mainly focused on the 4v4 matches lately.  A common problem I see at my level, top of silver or mid gold and below, is that people tend to drop at the beginning of the game.  Within the first five seconds of the game, you see the dreaded

> Player has left the game!

At that point you know the match is already one sided and it's very rare that the disadvantaged team wins the match. It just becomes exercise for both teams if the rest just don't already drop out.

I was just wondering if the higher ranks, particularly diamond, tend to have less dropped players?  I am leaning towards this it's to one's incentive to play for a fighting chance, at least, I would think.  **Is there a sloping trend in dropped players per match as the leagues get higher?**

Comment: is there even a way to measure this?

Comment: This is really two questions: (1) "What causes players to drop/leave games?" and (2) "Would any of those causes diminish in higher leagues?". Do note that reasons may sometimes be technical, especially in the first part of a game, and there's no reason to suppose that would really diminish with advancing league. (Though it would be harder to advance if one's computer dropped games, if most people experience it occasionally, the net impact is zero)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but when a player drops you should not be at a disadvantage. Your team can control the dropped player, and the resources are distributed among your team. This actually gives you an advantage because you can get tech faster than a normal game. This can even be abused - for example in 2v2, a player leaves immediately, and you can build a spawning pool almost instantly. Much faster than a 6-pool. I play a lot of 2v2 and when a player drops  at the beginning it's a good chance I'll win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to share a bit, I'm diamond in 4v4 solo queue and i play with some friends in 4v4 once in a while. I've never been silver so I don't know how many games players leave at the start of the game. But I don't see it very often in my leagues. Might be luck more than anything though. In fact, I don't remember last time someone left in my diamond league. But yeah, it did happen once in a while.

But like @tenfour commented, once a player leaves the game, his economy is shared to remaining players so you're actually at advantage here. You can either, get more barracks/gates/hatchery in order to keep up with the economy flowing in and rush as fast as you can with as much units as possible. Or you can tech up to higher tiers units. But keep in mind that it's still 3 army versus 4, so you should have much higher supply then them when you are attacking if you want a chance at breaking them.